# Difficulties with Farseer documentation

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics, farseer

I tried the "Texture to polygon" example in the Farseer documentation. 
https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation
But I always get this error message in the following line:

```
//Find the vertices that makes up the outline of the shape in the texture
Vertices  verts = PolygonTools.CreatePolygon(data, polygonTexture.Width, polygonTexture.Height, true);

No overload for method 'CreatePolygon' takes 4 arguments
```

Is there a mistake in the Farseer documentation or what is wrong?
What should I change in this line?

In addition, I get these two error messages in the following lines:

```
_list = BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(verts);
List<Fixture> compund = FixtureFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(World, _list, 1);

The name 'BayazitDecomposer' does not exist in the current context  
'FarseerPhysics.Factories.FixtureFactory' does not contain a definition for 'CreateCompoundPolygon'
```

What is wrong?

I have the following three usings in my code:

```
using FarseerPhysics.Dynamics;
using FarseerPhysics.Factories;
using FarseerPhysics.Common;
```

Should I add another using?

Comment: Your last two errors indicate some lack of reference to the necessary files.

Comment: Do you have the right `using FarseerPhysics` libraries included at the top?

Comment: I don't know if there is missing a using. For the moment, I use three usings. Should I add another using?

Comment: Try `FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition` for the Bayazit problem. I am curious, are these methods underlined in red before you compile, and if so, don't they provide some clue as to what library they think they're being called from? What happens when you right+click "Go To Definition" on them?

Comment: I get another error message when I do right+click "Go To Definition" on CreateCompoundPolygon: Cannot navigate to 'CreateCompoundPolygon' I don't know how to solve this problem?

Comment: That basically confirms in my mind that the libraries you need have not been included. It doesn't know how to reference the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all of your problems can be summed up by not including the right libraries. I will admit, the FarseerPhysics documentation you linked was not very helpful. You can see in their own source code, for example, that [BayazitDecomposer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1436514) is part of the `FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition` namespace, therefore you'd reference it by saying either

```
using FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition;
```

at the top, or just `using FarseerPhysics.Common;` and in your code:

```
Decomposition.BayazitDecomposer() //etc.
```

I'd recommend looking at other developers' sample code, or diving further into FarseerPhysics' source, in order to see what other libraries you're lacking.

I notice also in your `CreatePolygon` case that the method, according to the [BodyFactory](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1436573) definition I'm looking at, doesn't even return the `Vertices` type you believe it does. So in that instance, not only are you possibly missing the library you need, but when you include it, it will say the return type is wrong.

Perhaps the commenter who suggested that the sample code you're using is based on an older version of Farseer is correct, given these issues.

Answer (score 1):

when you download the file [Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Samples XNA](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/downloads/get/226767)!  Advanced Demo 1 has a example of "Texture to polygon"

The documentation of the page this outdated.